# How to set SerachView background white and text Color black

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I could not find any article on Xamarin android handling SearchView.

The searchView below will provide a black background and white textColor

1) I need to set the background color white and textColor white.
2) The keyboard wont go away if user decided not to use search. How to dismiss the keyboard after clicking the searchView?

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <SearchView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/sv" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/merchantListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to set text color to black

```
SearchView sv = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.sv);
int id = sv.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
TextView tv = (TextView)sv.FindViewById(id);
tv.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
```

You can click on the search glass icon in keyboard to dismiss it or set `sv.ClearFoucs()` whenever you need to dismiss focus for the SearchView.

Comment: Good code. I added one more line  tv.SetBackgroundColor((Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff")));
            tv.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black); How to know for sure search_src_text is the ID for SerachView?? How to dismiss it by clicking anywhere on the screen?

Comment: Now I know I can tap back Key to dismiss the Keyboard. As for UX consideration, user may want to tap anywhere on the screen to dismiss the keyboard. I m looking for this solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi Isham I added the code as you proposed but, the tv is null. I put the code in OnCreateOptionsMenu. Is this the place?

Comment: @Yaza whats your Android version?

Comment: @IshamMohamed my minimum android version is 4.1 API level 16.

Comment: @MilkBottle sorry for late reply for your question on "How to know for sure search_src_text is the ID for SerachView". Answer is reading the source code for Android SearchView. By reading the code, we can tweak many things that are not exposed for higher level API

Comment: @Yaza You'll get a null reference if you do the above changes before `SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);`. Please refer to this sample https://github.com/IshamMohamed/XamarinSearchView